# How to find the path to setup Laravel Aimeos cron job?

Tags: php, laravel, path, laravel-artisan

I am unable to find the path to Artisan. I need to execute this:

```
php /path/to/artisan aimeos:jobs "admin/job order/email/delivery order/email/payment order/service/delivery"
```

My project path is: `vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www/html/shop$`

I get the result:

> No command 'app' found, but there are 17 similar ones
>   app: command not found

Full path: `/Users/devika/Desktop/laraveltrusty/data/shop/artisan`

Comment: It should be whatever the path is whenever you run the artisan commands from the command line. Usually one directory above your app directory, so it should probably be `/var/www/html/shop`

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same result.

Comment: I did this:  * * * * * php /var/www/html/shop/artisan aimeos:jobs "admin/job order/email/delivery order/email/payment order/service/delivery"

Comment: I got this result: No command 'app' found, but there are 17 similar ones
app: command not found

Comment: Can you see in error log about the failure or cron ?

Comment: If you run that directly on the command line without the asterisks, does it work?  There is no `app` listed in your command, so it shouldn't referencing that, unless it's something inside of your laravel command script.

Comment: thanks, great help, it works!!!! I got this : Executing the Aimeos jobs for "default"